# Use other image as thumbnail for Sparkling Theme Polular Post Widget in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have installed Sparking Theme. I tried to use Sparkling Polular Post Widget to display my popular posts in the side bar. By default it shows a thumbnail which always shows the featured image. I want to show any other image as thumbnail, say the first image found in the post as thumbnail. Beacuse if any post doesn't have the featured image, it shows just blank, I want to show first image of the post as thumbnail.

Is it possible to somehow achieve it? I am new to wordpress and may be I a missing something. Please help.

[image]

Thanks
Manish

Comment: Upload your chosen image as feature image from your post detail page from wordpress admin so it will automatically come as thumbnail for popular post.

Answer (score 1):

you can try using this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoset-featured-image/ or this https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-add-thumbnail/ .the second one works out of the box .when you publish a post it checks for a featured image. If it does not find one, then it looks for the first image attached to the post and sets it as featured image